# Delegate event firing twice

Tags: jquery, delegates

This delegate event is firing twice (not always, sometimes).

```
client.bindButtonClickFunction = function(){

    $("#client-plugin").delegate(".client-button", "click", function()
    {
        var id = this.id.split('-')[2];
        client.retrieveMessageByID(id);
    });
};
```

I call the function after inserting all the ".client-button"'s.

Any thoughts on how to stop it? I tried event.stopPropagation(), and also undelegating and re-delegating to no avail.

This is in Chrome, as part of a Chrome plugin.

Comment: Difficult to say without further information. Most likely you call `bindButtonClickFunction` twice... btw. you don't need to wait for the `.client-button`s to be inserted, `delegate` works similar like `live`.

Comment: Did you try stopImmediatePropagation? http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: I just fixed a firing twice issue I was having.  Like @FelixKling said, I had my delegate() declaration inside of some $(document).ready() functions, essentially calling the function multiple times.

Comment: @Eric Di Bari: Why would a **delegate()** inside **$(document).ready()** get called twice? Can you explain that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on how you register the **delegate**, you might want to do:

```
$("#client-plugin").undelegate('event').delegate('event', ...)
```

Also, try to add a `return false` from your handler.

Comment: Would have answered the same. I suggest doing this and then testing again to see if it still gets called twice - if it does, you know the problem is in whatever calls the method being run twice, not the method itself.

Comment: @mrchief: I have the same problem, i.e I have trigger the function, and the class which is triggered is declared twice in my code, so when i click on that class, it fired the trigger twice, and if i use the return false then my checkbox is not checked, please would you tell any other solution?

Comment: @Suleman: `UnDelegate` should work in your case too. The second instantiation should un-register and then register your handler once. If you have more questions, open a new question and post some code.

Answer (score 10):

You need to stop immediate propagation

```
   $("#client-plugin").on(".client-button", "click", function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var id = this.id.split('-')[2];
    client.retrieveMessageByID(id);
});
```